# Android intent set getIntExtra as global variable

Tags: android, android-intent

I have three activities, Main, SecondActivity and ThirdActivity. I want to send int variable from Main to SecondActivity, and after that, send int(number) from Main(which I got) and SecondActivity to ThirdActivity.

MainActivity:

```
String Score = 0;

public void onNextClick(View view){
        Score++;
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("Answer", Score);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }
```

SecondActivity:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
int Score2 = intent.getIntExtra("Answer", 0);

public void onNextClick(View view){
        Score2++;
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ThirdActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("Answer2", Score2);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }
```

But I get error:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.kvizzadatak/com.kvizzadatak.SecondActivity}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException
>                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2174)
>                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
>                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
>                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1246)
>                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:212)
>                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5151)
>                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
>                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:684)
>                                                                    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>                                                                 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>                                                                    at com.kvizzadatak.ThirdActivity.(ThirdActivity.java:23)
>                                                                    at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
>                                                                    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1208)
>                                                                    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
>                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2165)
>                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298) 
>                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144) 
>                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1246) 
>                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:212) 
>                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5151) 
>                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
>                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
>                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868) 
>                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:684) 
>                                                                    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: I need to set that variable Score2 as global, but I cant..

Comment: in MainActivity you have taken it as `String` not `Int` check

Comment: @SunilP 
Yeah that mistake was fixed, but still my app crashes.

Comment: what is error now

Comment: In SecondActivity You have twice defined >>> Intent intent !

Answer (score 1):

If you want to put anything in a place where you can easily access it globally, you can use Shared Preference or your Global constants class. To use Shared Pref do the following

```
SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("your_prefs", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
editor.putInt("Answer2", score2);
editor.commit();
```

To access it you can use -

```
SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("your_prefs", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
int myIntValue = sp.getInt("Answer2", -1);
```

If you want to use Intents to transfer then your getIntent should be a part of Android lifecycle method. So you should do the below code in your `onCreate` method preferably.

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
int Score2 = intent.getIntExtra("Answer", 0);
```

Comment: what's '-1' for?

Comment: that -1 is a default value. If in case there is no value passed in intent then by default myIntValue will be initialized to -1. You can keep any default value here. Also in the next line you can check as well if myIntValue==-1 then do default operation but if you get some value you can do your calculations

Comment: About intent. If I set this in onCreate:
Intent intent = getIntent();
int Score2 = intent.getIntExtra("Answer", 0); Then I cannot access Score2 var in my other methods in order to send that var again.

Comment: This is not set statement. This is get Statement which means that in your previous activity you have used setter statements before starting this activity. so your Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("Answer", Score);
        startActivity(intent); should be in first activity anywhere as you have done. Then in OnCreate of SecondActivity use the get statement that i have shown above

Comment: Yes I understand that, but my main question is, how to putExtra the value I previously got from getIntExtra?

Comment: In your second activity class create a global variable.then in on create get the value from intent and save in that global variable. Then you can use this anywhere in the class. So when you do putExtra for score2, do the same for score1

Comment: To declare global variable do it like this public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    int score1;
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    getIntent() // do here}